# Problem with loading angular components dynamically when building with --prod option

Tags: angular, angular11, angular-ivy

I have an Angular application that I've recently upgraded from version 8 to version 11. Before the upgrade, everything worked fine. In this application, there are some components that are being loaded dynamically with the `ComponentFactoryResolver` class in Angular. There is a special decorator that saves the component class with a special name to a Map object to load them later. The decorator looks like this:

```
export default function PluginView(name: string) {
    return (ctor: new () => PluginBase) => {
        PluginViewManager.addPluginView(name, ctor);
    };
}

export class PluginViewManager {
    private static pluginViewByUniqueName = new Map<string, new () => PluginBase>();

    public static addPluginView(name: string, plugin: new () => PluginBase) {
        const uniqueName = name.toLowerCase();
        if (!this.pluginViewByUniqueName.has(uniqueName)) {
            this.pluginViewByUniqueName.set(uniqueName, plugin);
        }
    }

    public static getPluginView(uniqueName: string): new () => PluginBase {
        return this.pluginViewByUniqueName.get(uniqueName.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

The problem is because the components which are being loaded dynamically have been never used, They would not be loaded in Angular production build so the decorator would not be called. Is there any way to force the Angular compiler to load some special components and doesn't make any optimization there?

**Edit 1:** 
The code of dynamic loader component is Like below:

HTML file:

```
<ng-template component-host></ng-template>

<button *ngFor="let name of names" (click)="loadComponentByUniqueName(name)">{{ name }}</button>
```

TS file:

```
export class ComponentLoaderComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {
    public names: string[] = [];

    @ViewChild(ComponentDirective)
    private componentHost: ComponentDirective;

    constructor(
        public elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>,
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private chRef: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {
        this.names = PluginViewManager.getPluginUniqueNames();
    }

    public loadComponentByUniqueName(uniqueName: string): PluginBase {
        let instance: PluginBase;

        const loadedComponent = this.loadComponent<PluginBase>(plugin, this.visualizerService.currentView);
        instance = loadedComponent.instance;

        this.chRef.detectChanges();
        return instance;
    }

    public loadComponent<T>(view: new () => PluginBase): { instance: T, componentRef: ComponentRef<any> } {
        let instance: T;

        const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(view);
        const factoryClass = factory && factory.componentType;

        let componentRef: ComponentRef<any> = null;

        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(factoryClass);
        componentRef = this.componentHost.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

        instance = <T>componentRef.instance;

        return { instance: instance, componentRef: componentRef };
    }
}
```

Comment: lazy loading components became better with ivy. the problem is most probably you are trying to render some component inside of you lazy loaded component. could you provide its template and its ts?

Comment: I've edited the question and added the template and ts file of the component loader component.

Comment: I was rather asking about component the you are trying to render

Comment: They're just simple components with @PluginView decorator above them.

Comment: then just fix your problem with creating module inside of a file with component, which contains your plugin component and all of other components that are used inside of it. It would fix the problem because angular would analyze transitiveCompileScopes correctly